How to loop through PDF table using TableRow
I am using Flutter PDF package.
The first table row is a heading row.
In all rows below the heading row is where I would like to loop though table elements to populate PDF table.
I am not sure how to implement a loop using TableRow.
Any feedback will be helpful. Thank You
Here is my code:
pw.Table(border: pw.TableBorder.all(),children: [
            pw.TableRow(children: [
                pw.Padding(padding: const pw.EdgeInsets.all(8),child: pw.Text('Name')),
              ]),
            pw.TableRow(children: [pw.Padding(padding: const pw.EdgeInsets.all(8),child: pw.Text('Column 1 - Row 2')),
              ]),
          ]),


Try these:
import 'package:pdf/widgets.dart' as pw;

void generateTable() {
  final pdf = pw.Document();

  // Default data for the table
  final data = [
    ['Name', 'Age', 'City'], // Table titles
    ['John', '25', 'New York'],
    ['Alice', '30', 'London'],
    ['Bob', '28', 'Paris'],
  ];

  pdf.addPage(
    pw.Page(
      build: (context) => pw.Center(
        child: pw.Table(
          border: pw.TableBorder.all(),
          children: [
            // Create rows dynamically
            for (var row in data)
              pw.TableRow(
                children: row.map((cell) {
                  return pw.Padding(
                    padding: const pw.EdgeInsets.all(8),
                    child: pw.Text(cell),
                  );
                }).toList(),
              ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );

  // Save the PDF file or view it
}

